# Intellisense works for some pages, not others

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, visual-studio-express

I am editing some code behind pages using MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. Yesterday, the page responded to my typing - intellisense offered suggestions, variables and function names auto-capitalized, syntax errors gave me the little squiggly red line.

Today, some pages do that and some do not. There are a lot of posts, on this board and others, about intellisense not working, but they don't seem to apply.

My files are not part of a 'solution'. They are standalone aspx files with associated vb files. So refreshing the project does not apply. Tried CTRL-ALT-SPACE to clear out intellisense cache, not go.

This post looked promising:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652840/visual-web-developer-2010-intellisense-will-not-display-vb-suggestions

But I can't figure out exactly what's being said.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes after me: it just spontaneously started working again a few hours later. No idea why.